# How to compute triple product in 2D

Tags: math, vector, language-agnostic, 2d, cross-product

I am following [this](https://blog.winter.dev/2020/gjk-algorithm/) article on how to code the GJK algorithm for collision detection, but instead of doing it in 3D, I do it in 2D.

However, at one point there is this piece of code :

```cpp
bool Line(
    Simplex& points,
    vector3& direction)
{
    vector3 a = points[0];
    vector3 b = points[1];

    vector3 ab = b - a;
    vector3 ao =   - a;
 
    if (SameDirection(ab, ao)) {
        direction = ab.cross(ao).cross(ab);
    }

    else {
        points = { a };
        direction = ao;
    }

    return false;
}
```

As you can see he chains two cross product to find the next direction, but how could I do that in 2D ?

Here is a picture to make these vectors more clear :

[image: Graphic of the AB and AO vectors]

Comment: just a silly off topic note cross product in 2D has just single operand ... so it can not be used for combining of more vectors ... what you describing is 3D cross product using 2D vectors ... so for example `z=0.0` ...

Comment: Yes I should have been more clear. Since the result of the double cross product is on the same plane of the two vectors, it thought it would be possible to compute it in "2d". (Which is what John Alexiou replied with)

Comment: Did not analyse what you really doing (geometrical meaning) but yes most likely this is computable in 2D ... most likely using `dot` product for projecting some vector into perpendicular or other direction ... You still can use 2D cross to obtain the normal ... however there are ways to do it without too

Comment: For a single cross product, the result is not on the plane of the two vectors. So you need to assume 3D anyway before computing another cross product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector cross triple product in 3D is

**p** = **a**×(**b**×**c**)

The full expansion can be computed with the following matrix/vector product

```
|px|   | -ay*by-az*bz     ay*bx        az*bx      | | cx |
|py| = |    ax*by      -ax*bx-az*bz    az*by      | | cy |
|pz|   |    ax*bx         ay*bz      -ax*bx-ay*by | | cz |
```

There are multiple 2D projections of the above depending if none, one or two of the vectors **a**, **b** or **c** are out of plane (with a z component non-zero).

In your case all three vectors are in plane (`az=0`, `bz=0` and `cz=0`) which yields the following result

```
|px|   | -ay*by   ay*bx               0 | | cx |   | ay*(bx*cy-by*cx) |
|py| = |  ax*by  -ax*bx               0 | | cy | = | ax*(by*cx-bx*cy) |
| 0|   |      0       0    -ax*bx-ay*by | |  0 |   |                0 |
```

So there you have it. The right-hand side of the above is the result of **a**×(**b**×**c**) in 2D.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! In my case, for the `ab.cross(ao).cross(ab);` ab would be b, ao = c and ab = a right ? or is it ab = a, ao = b and ab = c ?

Comment: Ah I figured it out, since a x (b x c) is equivalent to (c x b) x a so in my case it would be ab x (ao x ab)

Comment: @TOOL - good point in depends on how the language is parsed for binary operators, but in this case it would be `(ab.cross(ao)).cross(ab)`.